# Proper way to check if URL parameter is empty?

Tags: php

The code works perfectly when I delete this right here:

```
if (empty($_GET['tag'])){
    header("Location: http://www.home.com");
}
```

I'm trying to say if the url (`tag=`) is empty then head back to homepage.
This is what the search button looks like:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testdb");
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']);
    header("Location: tags?tag=".$_POST['search']."");
}
```

When I do reinsert that code above (`if(empty)`) it keeps redirecting to the home page.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="tag" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
    <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for tags...">
    <input id="search_submit" name="submit-search" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the value you are searching for? `var_dump($_GET);`

Comment: Are you sure your second `if` statement is even firing?  You're checking to see if `$_POST['submit-search']` is set, but then referencing `$_POST['search']` after...  Also, why are you setting `$search` but then never using it?

Comment: It's searching for what ever the user searches in the search bar. For example, if someone searches for `food` it should put `food` in the `tag=` and search for all things `food`.

Comment: Where is your input with name "tag" .. It will now always be empty, or basically not set

Comment: @RobertC I didn't know it can work without the $search, I added my html

Comment: So what does `GET` have when it redirects to the root? (I'd invert the code blocks, so the execution order matches the reading order)

Comment: @Daniel the `tag=` is always going to have something in it.

Comment: @chris85 `GET` I hope I explain this right.. the way have everything set up is that when you click on a tag it turns into a `GET` and inserts into the URL and searches for that. So if the tag you clicked on is `animals` it will be a `GET` and that will be inserted into the `tag=`

Comment: O, I see.. It's given in your second header redirect. So what you want to test for is if the $_POST['search'] is empty?

Comment: Yes, I get the concept, but is that actually what is there? Output `$_GET['tag']` in the `empty` check where the redirect occurs. See what you have. Is it empty? If it is output `$_POST['search']` on the previous page, if that is populated show us the rewrite rules.

Comment: @Daniel @chris85 I got it! I'm so sorry for any confusion! I had to do this: `if ($_GET['tag'] === '')` so if the `tag=`(`nothing`)  then head back. plus it doesn't redirect if it isn't nothing! Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy Coding :-)